# Portable Xiaomi speaker passive radiator need space?

Tags: batteries, speakers, portable

I have a Xiaomi MI portable speaker. I'm planning to replace the battery. I made space by cutting a little plastic to fit 2 18650 cylindrical cells, or a single 26650 cell.

I noticed there is empty space there, and with my primitive knowledge I suppose the passive radiator needs this empty space to work. This radiator is at the back of the speaker:

[image]

The two speakers are on the other side and you can see the one's hole here, as it has been removed:

[image]

So, crucial question: Will putting the cells over there ruin the bass?

[image: Before]
(Before)

[image: After fitting a 2nd battery]
(After fitting a 2nd battery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bass reflex speakers are mass-spring resonant systems. The main driver applies pressure to the spring, which is the volume of air inside the box. At the other end of the spring, there is the mass of air inside the vent. This is tuned so the resonance of this mass-spring system supplements the output of the main drivers at bass frequencies.

Passive radiators (PR) work pretty much the same, except the resonant mass is the PR diaphragm, and it has a suspension which adds another spring. The nice thing about PRs is they allow designs that would not be possible with a vent, because the vent would be too long (which sounds like woosh-woosh when the air moves, plus it resonates like an organ pipe), or the vent would just not fit in the box, which is the case here.

So what's gonna happen is that the resonance frequency is going to shift upwards by something vaguely resembling the square root of the ratio of the before/after volumes. Vaguely, because the PR suspension is a large part of the spring, and that's not going to change.

Since the additional battery is tiny compared to the internal volume, I think the difference will be small, and if you hear something, you'll probably be able to EQ it anyway.

Whatever you do make absolutely sure it doesn't rub or vibrate against anything, because that will sound like there's a big hornet stuck inside the box.

Comment: The mod worked and it has no audible difference indeed. This speaker is incredibly VFM and now just got even more legit. 

What i want to ask you, from a physics standpoint, is how is it possible for this air mass to resonate at a continuous spectrum of frequencies? I thought the resonant wavelengths for the closed cavity was 1/2 wavelength and it's multiples? So it's some dicrete frequencies.

Comment: Glad it worked! It's not a 1/2 wavelength cavity resonance, in fact you want to avoid that because cavities also resonate at all the multiples of the base resonant frequency, which would make peaks all over the midrange. It's a mass-spring system, so it has one resonant peak. It is lossy, low Q, so the peak isn't sharp, more like a wide bump. This bump is placed by design right at the frequency where output from the main drivers fall off, so it extends the bass response from the main drivers.

Comment: We do not know if the speaker is high quality with little speakers that produce some bass then a low Q passive radiator extends the bass with a wide bandwidth, or if the speaker is cheap will little speakers that produce almost no bass then a high Q passive radiator makes bong, bong noises called, "one note bass". I heard a very expensive little speaker on demo at Costco and I could not belie its bass was so good.

Comment: Incredible what you can learn in stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

The entire speaker is too small to produce low bass frequencies. It might produce down to 100Hz then it misses producing more than 2 octaves of bass.

The internal space and passive radiator are designed for the best bass but your 2 batteries changed it for less bass.

Why are you changing its original battery? Did it originally have one 3.7V cell and with two new cell in series (7.4V) won't the amplifiers and speaker drivers blow up?
Do you have a new charger for the new batteries?

Comment: Thanks! No i'm just putting them in parallel. The original battery wasn't good and has worn out now so i will replace it for more play time, carrying along it's thermistor.  Are we talking about audible difference now?

Comment: Maybe the original battery and/or charger was poor quality and cheap. Instead of using two new batteries (which also might be poor quality) in parallel then use one good Name Brand high quality battery (and try using a new charger) to have the original space inside the speaker and the identical to new sound. I told my son I heard a demo of a very expensive little speaker that sounded wonderful. He bought a cheap similar speaker as yours for me. It sounded awful and its battery was garbage.

Comment: Well the charger is embedded to the main PCB. It's a single cell lithium charger. Since it probably doesnt mind about capacity i could put 2 in parallel to double the capacity in the same voltage. Here is a legit teardown of the speaker:
https://youtu.be/i4bS46LaQzw

Comment: The original battery and the ones you will parallel might be junk or maybe the charger circuit does not fully charge the battery.

Comment: No the previous battery was junk. It had aged badly. The new batteries work and get charged perfectly!